After downloading WSL Ubuntu installation username problem
I got the following message when trying to install Ubuntu in WSL.
Installing, this may take a few minutes...  
The parameter is incorrect.  
Please create a default UNIX user account.    
The username does not need to match your Windows username.  
Enter new UNIX username: ▂ 


What should I do now?

The command prompt is prompting you to enter a username for the user of your new Ubuntu  installation in WSL. You can choose whatever username you want for your Ubuntu user. For example, your username can be your own name or a string of random alphanumeric characters, however to avoid potential issues with programs or scripts that might interact with your username, it's recommended to use a username with at least 1 character.
